# How to keep default CSS styles on arbitrary browsers while also using webkit styles for slider (range input)?

Tags: html, css, webkit

#### Background

I want to style a slider (range input element) using CSS, such as `<input type="range" min="5" max="20" step="1" value="10">`.

I know that I can use webkit to achieve this to work in some browsers, e.g. Chrome. However, it seems like I *must* use `input[type=range] { -webkit-appearance: none; }` in CSS file in order for the other webkit styles to work. But, if I use `-webkit-appearance: none;`, it changes the slider style in other browsers, e.g. Firefox.

I know that I can use other selectors like `::-moz-range-thumb` or `::-ms-thumb` to provide styling for other browsers. But I assume there are browsers out there that wouldn't work with `::-webkit-slider-thumb` or `::-moz-range-thumb` or `::-ms-thumb`.

#### My main question

Is it possible to use webkit styling while *also* having a default style option that will work in any arbitrary browser that supports the range input element?

I would prefer a CSS *only* solution, but would be open to a solution that requires javascript.

#### Example code

The code below works as expected in webkit browsers like Chrome, but changes the style to be unusable for my purposes in other browsers. (Again, I know about `::-moz-*` and `::-ms-*`, but I'm assuming there are other browsers not covered by those.)

Link to below code: https://jsfiddle.net/0tz9jc6r/7/

```html
<input type="range" min="5" max="20" step="1" value="10">
```

```css
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 300px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: lightgray;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 5px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: skyblue;
    border: solid gray 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest – and seemingly reliable – way would be to use CSS feature queries, in which we can test for support of a particular property:value pair, as follows:

```css
input[type=range] {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 300px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: lightgray;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 5px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: skyblue;
  border: solid gray 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  width: 30px;
}

@supports (-webkit-appearance) {
  input[type=range],
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="5" max="20" step="1" value="10">
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wmbd1pau/).

This – according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries) – seems to have good browser support, at around 97% (at the time of writing).

References:

- [CSS Feature Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#testing_for_the_support_of_a_given_css_property_or_a_prefixed_version), at Mozilla Developer Network.
- [Feature Queries, the `@supprts` rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-conditional-3/#at-supports), at W3.org.